# MySQL command line issue

Tags: mysql, batch-file, command-line

I am in trouble executing a .bat script which execute some commands in mysql. I can not figure out what is going on. My problem is executing this windows command line below:

```
c:\mysql.exe -h instance -udbuser -pPass db -e "INSERT INTO db.table1 (SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT(TRIM(co_ano),'-',TRIM(co_mes),'-1'),'"', '') as col1,REPLACE(TRIM(col2_temp),'"', '') as col2, REPLACE(TRIM(col3_temp),'"', '') as col3, REPLACE(TRIM(col4_temp),'"', '') as col4, REPLACE(TRIM(col5_temp),'"', '') as col5, REPLACE(TRIM(col6_temp),',','.') as col6, REPLACE(TRIM(col7_temp),',','.') as col7 FROM db.temp_table1);"
```

When I split the command and execute it in parts, it works fine. Example:

```
 c:\mysql.exe -h instance -udbuser -pPass db
```

It works and then now I am in mysql>

In mysql command line when I execute this:

```
mysql>INSERT INTO db.table1 (SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT(TRIM(co_ano),'-',TRIM(co_mes),'-1'),'"', '') as col1, REPLACE(TRIM(col2_temp),'"', '') as col2, REPLACE(TRIM(col3_temp),'"', '') as col3, REPLACE(TRIM(col4_temp),'"', '') as col4, REPLACE(TRIM(col5_temp),'"', '') as col5, REPLACE(TRIM(col6_temp),',','.') as col6, REPLACE(TRIM(col7_temp),',','.') as col7 FROM db.temp_table1);
```

and so, it works.

Why is the first command not working? I need to execute this command using a batch file.

I would like to add that the command below works fine

```
c:\mysql.exe -h instance -udbuser -pPass db -e "OPTIMIZE TABLE temp_table1"
```

MySQL Ver 8.0.17

Someone can help me?

Comment: Try doubling _all_ inner double quotes  e.g. as `REPLACE(TRIM(col3_temp),'""', '') as col3` instead of `REPLACE(TRIM(col3_temp),'"', '') as col3`

Comment: I can clearly see that your `-e` string is doublequoted, however the problem line has embedded doublequotes within that string. I'm going to assume therefore that in order to pass the string to mysql.exe, you're doing to have to escape those internal doublequotes. The usual way to do that is to use a backslash, `'\"'`, although there are other possibilities, like doubling up the internal doublequotes, `'""'`.